# Django template - How to get key, value(list) from a dictionary in the request context

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, templates

I have my context in a html template and I'm not able to read the value which is a List of objects from key in my dictionary.

This is my context:

```
{'month_posts': 
   defaultdict(<class 'list'>, 
       {'October': [<Post: Set pagination>, <Post: Test pagination>],
        'November': [<Post: Redesign Model>]}
   )
}
```

This is the for loop I'm implementing to get the key and value:

```
{% for month in month_posts %}
   ...
   <h3>{{ month | capfirst }}</h3>
   {% for post in month_posts[month] %}
      <a href="#">{{ post.title }}</a>
   {% endfor %}
   ...
{% endfor %}
```

I got this error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '[month]' from 'month_posts[month]'
```

I have tried these:

```
{% for month, post in month_posts.items %}
```

I got no errors but also no data in my template.

Do you have any idea how I could get the List in the value of the Dictionary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you returned context(month_posts) with the render function?

Comment: Yes, I returned it.
context = {'month_posts': month_posts, 'categories': categories }

This is my context.

{'month_posts': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'November': [<Post: Redesign Model>]}), 'categories': <QuerySet [<Category: django>, <Category: python>]>}

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{% for post in posts %}
```

You can do that because you have:

```
{% for month, posts in month_posts.items %}
```

... which iterates both over the keys (`month`) and values (`posts`) of `month_posts`

Comment: When I do this I got nothing in my template. It does not print anything.

Comment: You changed your question, did you change that in your code too?

Comment: Yes, I did. I paste it wrong. I was a little stressed. I actually solved it, and answered the question with your comment, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating my List, in my views.py, without:

```
from collections import defaultdict

month_posts = defaultdict(list)
for paged_post in paged_posts:
    month = paged_post.publish_date.strftime('%B')
    month_posts[month].append(paged_post)
```

This was causing the issue where I couldn't read the list in month_posts context key. I did implemented as:

```
# Posts by month
month_posts = {}
for paged_post in paged_posts:
    month = paged_post.publish_date.strftime('%B')
    if not month in month_posts:
        month_posts[month] = []
        month_posts[month].append(paged_post)
    else:
        month_posts[month].append(paged_post)
```

So, in the template I was able to read as:

```
{% for month, posts in month_posts.items %}
```

and

```
{% for post in posts %}
```